# Could not perform segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm trying to perform segue by this method:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"liveStream" sender:self];
```

and i am getting this error:

```
reason: 'Could not perform segue with identifier 'liveStream'. A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform.'
```

I couldn't find any solution. Do you guys have any idea how to solve it?
I ll be really thankful.

Comment: thanks @Larme, i found the solution there :) but for other guys, I'm using CUSTOM segue and for this u have to have a custom class, which i have not. Solution was to change type of segue from CUSTOM to another.

Answer (score 1):

You did this .?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuNiq.png)

Check exactly the Identifier